# How to kickstart Red Hat from DVD

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, kickstart

I learnt that there is a way where we can automate the installation of Red Hat using a kickstart script. However, everywhere they talk about doing that from bootable floppy image.

I have a single DVD of Red Hat (RHEL5). Can anyone tell how can I kickstart the installation using the kickstart script, i.e., where do I place the ks.cfg file on the disk and what command should be given at the boot prompt? (Kickstart from DVD and not from any network.)

Please suggest what I need to do to achieve the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `ks.cfg` at the top level of your DVD.

If you are using the method described at [Making the Kickstart File Available](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-putkickstarthere.html) and [Making an Installation Boot CD-ROM](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s2-steps-make-cd.html), that means you should copy the `ks.cfg` into the `isolinux` folder you are using to make the CD/DVD.

Or you can make a boot USB drive using the instructions under [Alternative Boot Methods](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/ch02s04.html#sect-New_Users-Alternative_Boot_Methods).

Or you can put it anywhere you like and  type `linux ks=/path/to/ks.cfg` at the boot prompt.
There are several options for `/path/to/ks.cfg`, including HTTP, NFS, CD/DVD, hard disk, and DHCP/TFTP.  See [Starting a Kickstart Installation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-startinginstall.html) for all the options.

Comment: thanx... it worked.